# Adding Google Tag manager <noscript> tag after body tag

Tags: layout, google-tag-manager

I need to place noscript tag of gtm just after closing body tag.

Comment: You have to need <noscript> code just before closing </body> tag right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `<noscript>` tag after body tag, then need to set your template `before.body.end` where you have to called your template for set `<noscript>` tag.

Follow below steps:

Your xml file set your template in `before.body.end`

**Example:**

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\GoogleTag" name="bock_name" template="Vendor_Module::yourtemplete.phtml" after="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Put your `<noscript>` code in yourtemplete.phtml file

After you can able to show your `<noscript>` code just after closing body tag.

Hope it help!